# Automating the testing Android Applications?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, testing

Hi people I have a serious problem at hand, I need to know about some tool that will automate the black box testing of the Android applications made using HTML, JavaScript , CSS for the native apps I am using Robotium as the testing tool to automate the black box testing of the android applications but I can't find anything that is good enough to automate the testing of the apps made using PhoneGap.

Comment: Robotium 4.2 has full support for PhoneGap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Gorilla Logic testing tool..Download **MonkeyTalk** tool from [here....](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk)

Comment: Can you propose some other tool as I am facing a lot of discrepancies with this tool

Comment: hey then you can use selenium tool for android...

Comment: I have already used robotium to test native android applications but the problem with it is that it is not able to recognize the web components and hence applications which are a blend of web + some android (java), can't really be tested efficiently hence making the process cumbersome for us.Any other suggestion regarding this.

Comment: @Coder, Iam looking for a similar tool. What types of problems did you have with MonkeyTalk?

Comment: @Coder, could you give a very short sum up regarding those discrepancies?

Comment: MonkeyTalk won't work for black box testing. You need access to the source code

Answer (score 0):

[NativeDriver](http://code.google.com/p/nativedriver/) might work for you.